# Question regarding prisma, postgress and the DateTime datatype

Tags: postgresql, time, next.js, prisma

What are the pros or/and cons of using a string to save time in a database? I am currently building an application that has a number of venues, each venue has an opening and closing time, some have mid-day breaks e.g open from 9am-1pm and then 4pm -12am(midnight). I have tried to save a solo time block in primsa using the following;

```
const res = await prisma.openingTime.create({
    data:{
      venueId:"cley5ndru0001bza4gp0phwyy",
      dayOfWeek: 6,
      openTime: new Date(),
      closeTime: new Date()
    }
  })
```

Although I can save a specific time by using `new Date("08-03-2023T09:00:00.000Z")` I find this not really achieving the desired results as I do not want the date. I have researched pretty much all day and found possible solutions such as adding @db.Time(0), however, this does not work. I still get the date and time. So my question is how can I add only the time to the db or would using a string be bad practise and potentially cause issues further down the line when I want to add a booking system? I'm led to believe that a string would require more coding to format simple things like differentiating between am and pm, and displaying if the venue is currently open or not based on the day of the week and current hour of the day.

Comment: All downsides of text-based format for any data type are really just space, performance and the fact that if you plan to process it later, you'll have to reimplement type-specific functionalities, or just cast. Prisma [should be able to let you](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/introduction-to-data-types#time) use PostgreSQL native [time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE).

Comment: PostgreSQL [`tsmultirange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) would be even more handy, if you can [make it work in Prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3287). Those would let you store multiple time ranges with gaps, in a single value, that you can later easily process and compare with [dedicated functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

Comment: The best way to model that in PostgreSQL is to use four columns of type `time`, with appropriate check constraints to ensure consistency.